# Getting data from server in objective c class

Tags: objective-c, class

Im trying to make a class where when I create an instance of that class and pass a username and password to the class it sends it to the server and gives whether its a valid password or whether theres an error. When I try to access the response variable from the instance I get null. I suspect that the methods begin called  -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection is happening before the variable is being accessed. Is there a better way to access the variable or call the method so it happens before the variable is accessed

Login View Controller.h

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)Login:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *username;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *password;

@end
```

Login View Controller.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "Users.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

@synthesize username, password;

/*
-(IBAction)Login:(id)sender{

     Users *user = [[Users alloc] init];
     [user Login:username.text :password.text];

        if ([user.serverResponse  isEqual: @"Status:Created"]) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"home" sender:nil];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@""
                              message:@"Username or Password is incorrect"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",user.serverResponse);

}

@end
```

Users Class.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Users : NSObject

- (void)Login:(NSString*)username :(NSString*)password;

- (void)Signup:(NSString*)username :(NSString*)password :(NSString*)password_confirmation :(NSString*)email;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *response;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *serverResponse;

@end
```

Users Class.m

```
#import "Users.h"
#define loginURL @"linktoserver"
#define signupURL @"linktoserver"

@implementation Users

@synthesize response, serverResponse;

    - (void)Login:(NSString*)username :(NSString*)password{

        NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        self.response = data;

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:loginURL];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

        // Http Method

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


        // Intializes Post Data

        NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username, password];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [request setHTTPBody:[postData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        // Intializes Connection Request

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        [connection start];

    }


#pragma Connection

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data

{

    [response appendData:data];

}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{


    serverResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response

                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}
```

Comment: Try to use `self.response` instead of `response`. I am not sure how you implemented, but there could be problem.
BTW, `NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];` and then 
`self.response = data;` is not Apple-like. :-)

Comment: ill upload my .h files

Comment: so instead of self.response change to just response?

Comment: Vise versa. You should always use getter/setter methods except in the init mehtod (read more @ Apple documentation: http://goo.gl/FDuAxa ).

Comment: Why don' you use ARC?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62703/discussion-between-michael-dorner-and-phil-pilon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection with delegates (to simplify the process):

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request 
                                 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
       if (!error && data){ // here you can check also response.statusCode if needed
            NSString *serverResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   completion(serverResponse);
            }); 
       }else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   completion(nil);
                   //show some alert about no connection etc 
            }); 
       }
}] resume];
```

add completion to your method

```
- (void) login:(NSString*)username 
      password:(NSString*)password  
    completion:(void (^)(NSSring *response))completion
```

and then compare response in the completion in the loginViewController

```
[user login:@"aaa" password:@"bbb" completion:^(NSString *response) {
    if ([response isEqualToString:@"ccc"]){
        // success!
    }else{
        // alert
    }
};
```

Comment: exactly what i needed thanks ill try to implement it

Comment: does the NSURL Session go in - (void)Login:(NSString*)username :(NSString*)password

Comment: yep. you remove NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; [connection start]; and delegate methods and add the code above with the Session

Comment: whats parameter for completion [user Login:username.text password:password.text completion:?];